Falsifying Business Records; Why is Jury Unanimity Not Required
Let me preface, this is not a political post, and please refrain from discussing political beliefs in the answers.
In the recent case about falsifying business records, former president Trump was found guilty. Many lay people were upset about the jury instructions:

"Although you must conclude unanimously that the defendant conspired
to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by
unlawful means, you need not be unanimous as to what those unlawful
means were."

I was discussing this with a friend, and I as a lay person found the logic sound. But before speaking more on the topic I decided to do some research. I was unable to find any precedent (I only used google, again, lay person) but I did find RICHARDSON v. UNITED STATES 130 F. 3d 765. That case seemed to outline the opposite of what I believed:

A jury in a §848 case must unanimously agree not only that the
defendant committed some “continuing series of violations,” but also
about which specific “violations” make up that “continuing series.”
Pp. 3–11.

I understand that this case is federal, not NY, nor is it a perfect match, but I am unfamiliar with how wide reaching precedent is. In the interest of keeping this to a single question, what is an applicable precedent, if RICHARDSON v. UNITED STATES is not.

I also question if judges and even this particular judge routinely give such instructions to the jury. If not why the specific mention of the concept here? In general I do not understand the logic behind it. If there is no SPECIFIC  action that there is unanimous agreement that a law was broken by it, then there is nothing he has done that he  has been proven  guilty of . They are ALL matter of debate.

The rule under New York State law is not necessarily the rule under federal law. Nothing requires that they be the same. And Trump's most recent case was in state court, while the case you reference is from a federal court.

After doing more reading and thinking, I think 'Intent' is the main difference here. You could theoretically prove intent, while having no evidence to show what exactly the crime was. A hypothetical scenario would be a phone call where the defendant says "If I do this and you go to jail, don't mention me." It would show that the defendant intended to "commit another crime or to aid or conceal the commission thereof" without necessarily providing evidence of the intended crime.

@Schmerel I believe the reason this was mentioned in this case by this judge because the defense has made an argument that the jury not only needs to unanimously agree not only that the prosecution has met their burden but also that they must agree on the specifics how that burden was met. In other words, if the jury all agreed that Prof. Plum killed the victim but half of them think it was in the library with the knife and the other half think it was in the ballroom with the rope, the defense said that should result in a hung jury. I understand this will be argument using during appeal.

The logic of Richardson doesn't apply here. In Richardson, the jury was not unanimous in agreeing which acts committed by the defendant broke the law. As the court points out, that ruling is "consistent with a tradition of requiring juror unanimity where the issue is whether a defendant has engaged in conduct that violates the law". However, here the jury did have to be unanimous in agreeing what specific conduct of Trump's violated the law.

Richardson would be like if someone fired two bullets and the jury instructions didn't require the jury to agree on which shot was a crime. Maybe half the jury thought only the first bullet was fired in self-defense and half the jury thought only the second bullet was fired in self-defense, but they all agreed that there was one unlawful shot. Trump is like if someone fired two bullets and the jury instructions said the jury didn't have to agree on which bullet struck the victim.

I wonder if Jen and I read the same article. It does give a number of cases the authors claim are similar enough:

In fact, the New York Court of Appeals, the state’s highest court, considered this issue in People v. Taveras—and found that only intent is required. In Taveras, the defendant challenged his sentence under § 175.10, along with a number of other offenses, including a charged object offense. While considering sentencing matters, the court held, “Read as a whole, it is clear that falsifying business records in the second degree is elevated to a first-degree offense on the basis of an enhanced intent requirement … not any additional actus reus element.”
In 2015, the First Department of the New York Supreme Court’s Appellate Division—whose rulings are binding on Justice Merchan—applied Taveras in a case structurally similar to Trump’s. (Trial courts in New York are, confusingly, referred to as “Supreme Courts”; the Appellate Division constitutes the intermediate appeals courts, while the Court of Appeals is the court of last resort.) People v. Thompson concerned a defendant convicted of § 175.10—along with “offering a false instrument for filing in the first degree”—for “ma[king] a false entry on a form regarding his purported disposal of a firearm … with the intent to commit or conceal his unlawful possession of the firearm.” The First Department upheld the conviction even though Thompson was not charged with the object offense of unlawful possession.
As in the Trump case, in Thompson, the Manhattan district attorney charged § 175.10 without charging the underlying object offense. Here, the appeals court found that the district attorney was not required to prove that the object offense had been committed. “The People were not required to establish that [the] defendant committed, or was convicted of, the crime he intended to conceal,” the First Department ruled, pointing to Taveras. That seems pretty definitive. And indeed, Justice Merchan cites Thompson in his ruling on Trump’s motion to dismiss, stating that the statute “does not require that the ‘other crime’ actually be committed. Rather, all that is required is that the defendant … act[] with a conscious aim and objective to commit another crime.”
A series of additional cases from New York’s Fourth Department provides further support for this read of the statute. These cases aren’t precedential for Merchan, but they’re still a helpful guide for how New York courts have previously interpreted the statute. In People v. McCumiskey, People v. Houghtaling, People v. Crane, and People v. Holley, a jury convicted a defendant under § 175.10 but deadlocked or acquitted on the charged object offense. And in each of those cases, the appellate court upheld the conviction. In McCumiskey, for example, the Fourth Department held, “The jury could therefore convict defendant of falsifying business records if the jury concluded that defendant had the intent to commit or conceal another crime, even if he was not convicted of the other crime.” Justice Merchan cites McCumiskey alongside Thompson in his ruling on Trump’s motion to dismiss.

Aside from that the NYT pointed to a SCOTUS case on the federal level. The somewhat obscure (not much of a Wikipedia summary) Schad v. Arizona
. I'm not surprised that few have attempted to summarize that case, because SCOTUS essentially decided that no single test can decide whether things are or aren't 'combinable' alternatives for aggravating factors. They start by presenting a different case Gipson and do a long takedown against it (even though it wasn't the case at hand!)

The defendant in Gipson was charged with violating 18 U.S.C. § 2313, which prohibited knowingly "receiv[ing], conceal[ing], stor[ing], barter[ing], sell[ing] or dispos[ing] of" any stolen vehicle or aircraft moving in interstate commerce, and was convicted after the trial judge charged the jury that it need not agree on which of the enumerated acts the defendant had committed. The Fifth Circuit reversed, reasoning that the defendant's right to "jury consensus as to [his] course of action" was violated by the joinder in a single count of "two distinct conceptual groupings," receiving, concealing, and storing forming the first grouping (referred to by the court as "housing"), and bartering, selling, and disposing ("marketing") constituting the second. Id., at 456-459. [...]

SCOTUS then says that in their view the appeals court was wrong in that case (but funnily enough that case was itself not appealed to SCOTUS, so the precedential value of what SCOTUS said there about it is somewhat unclear):

This approach rests on the erroneous assumption that any statutory alternatives are ipso facto independent elements defining independent crimes under state law, and therefore subject to the axiomatic principle that the prosecution must prove independently every element of the crime.

To finally get to this (about the controversy that they were asked to decide):

The issue presented here is similar, for under Arizona law neither premeditation nor the commission of a felony is formally an independent element of first-degree murder; they are treated as mere means of satisfying a mens rea element of high culpability.
[...] Whether or not everyone would agree that the mental state that precipitates death in the course of robbery is the moral equivalent of premeditation, it is clear that such equivalence could reasonably be found, which is enough to rule out the argument that this moral disparity bars treating them as alternative means to satisfy the mental element of a single offense.

So, essentially SCOTUS decided that a jury did not need unanimity in deciding the aggravating factors, in detail. Some jurors may think it's one, and some another, as long as all of them agreed that there was one aggravating factor from the those listed by the law.

In these cases, as in litigation generally, different jurors may be persuaded by different pieces of evidence, even when they agree upon the bottom line. Plainly there is no general requirement that the jury reach agreement on the preliminary factual issues which underlie the verdict.

Arguably, this is not exactly the same thing as not being able to decide which "object offense" was committed as the aggravating factor, but I can see why the NYT would mention this case.
Now going back to the Lawfare article, it seems the judge did in fact narrow down some of the alternatives that the jury was allowed to consider as "object offense", box B in the diagram.

So, as long as all jurors agreed Trump intended to commit one of those, they could use that as aggravating factor, even if different jurors preferred a different box among the "B" alternatives.

Richardson (1999) does mention Schad (1991) a few times. The most relevant bit probably being:

this Court has indicated that the Constitution itself limits a State's power to define crimes in ways that would permit juries to convict while disagreeing about means, at least where that definition risks serious unfairness and lacks support in history or tradition. Schad v. Arizona  501 U.S., at 632-633 (plurality opinion); id., at 651 (SCALIA, J., concurring) ("We would not permit . . . an indictment charging that the defendant assaulted either X on Tuesday or Y on Wednesday . . ."). We have no reason to believe that Congress intended to come close to, or to test, those constitutional limits when it wrote this [CCE] statute.

And (right above that) they discuss what seems to be their main issue taking any alternative in a CCE case:

The CCE statute's breadth also argues against treating each individual violation as a means, for that breadth aggravates the dangers of unfairness that doing so would risk. Cf. Schad v. Arizona, supra, at 645 (plurality opinion). The statute's word "violations" covers many different kinds of behavior of varying degrees of seriousness. The two chapters of the Federal Criminal Code setting forth drug crimes contain approximately 90 numbered sections, many of which proscribe various acts that may be alleged as "violations" for purposes of the series requirement in the statute.

I.e. SCOTUS thought in Richardson that 90 alternatives is too many. They also reasoned that

in making CCE a separate crime, rather than a sentencing provision, Congress sought increased procedural protections for defendants.

(Also, Scalia as well as Souter and Rehnquist agreed with both decisions, albeit Scalia wrote his own concurring opinion in the former. Three justices had changed on the SCOTUS bench in the meantime, but among those who did not, O'Connor and Kennedy agreed with Schad but disagreed with Richardson. Only Stevens had the opposite trajectory.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Quinta Juresic and Tyler McBrian explain this is their article for Lawfare, "What Must Prosecutors Prove in Trump’s NY Trial?"
They acknowledge there is no case law directly on point, and others speculate this may be an avenue of argument on appeal.
But the theory that jury unanimity is not required with respect to the object offence or unlawful means is based on a plurality holding of the Supreme Court of the United States that said (as paraphrased in the above article): "while agreement among jurors is required as to the elements of an offense, it is not required as to the means. That is, the jurors must agree as to which crime was committed, but not necessarily how it was committed."
The "another crime" or unlawful means has been understood in Mr. Trump's charges to be merely a means by which 175.10 was committed.
As an analogy, in relation to New York burglary offences, the Court of Appeals for the 2nd Circuit has said, "A specific intent to commit a particular crime upon entry is not a material element of the offense under New York law." Like the offence with which Mr. Trump was convicted, the burglary statute only required "intent to commit a crime therein." Jurors need not be unanimous about which crime a burglar intended to commit once inside.
There is no general rule that applies across all offences. Each is interpreted separately, and each may result in different requirements of unanimity. There is nothing necessarily incongruous with the federal offence quoted in the question having different requirements than a different federal offence or the New York offence Mr. Trump was convicted of.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I would think that the case is very ripe for appeal as the Constitution and Amendments spell out that the charges must be specific. And as the Constitution and Amendments are supreme to any State law, would overrule the judge's instructions. Ramos V Louisiana require unanimity of the jury on the charges. SCOTUS ruled that it applied in Federal and State Courts. The judge's instructions were that the jury had to be unanimous in the conviction but they only needed to find Trump guilty of one of the  add-on charges and not that they all had to agree on which one. One was a Federal elections violation that the State court has no jurisdiction over. Trump Jury's instructions. https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/24699534-trump-ny-criminal-trial-jury-instructions
Richardson v US 526 U.S. 813 (1999) further added the requirements to the add-ons being unanimous so that it too would apply to Trump's case. Both of these cases lead to the 6th Amendment requiring that a person be informed of the nature and cause of the accusation. Allowing the jury to pick a charge, any add-on charge does not meet that requirement. The 14th Amendment also applies as that is where the requirements on the State courts become the same as in the Federal courts. If Federal Law says something, then the State has to accept it as Federal Law is supreme to State Law.
United States v Caril 105 U.S. 611 (1881) "In an indictment upon a statute, it is not sufficient to set forth the offense in the words of the statute unless those words of themselves fully, directly, and expressly, without any uncertainty or ambiguity, set forth all the elements necessary to constitute the offense intended to be punished, and the fact that the statute in question, read in the light of the common law and of other statutes on the like matter, enables the court to infer the intent of the legislature, does not dispense with the necessity of alleging in the indictment all the facts necessary to bring the case within that intent." The Prosecutor never brought those charges to the case until it was before the jury to come up with a verdict. It was not in the Indictment.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Jen, without them deciding on a verdict that included the additional charges, they could not convict him of a felony.  https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/24699534-trump-ny-criminal-trial-jury-instructions   Starting at page 30 you find the instructions concerning the add-on crimes. "Although you must conclude unanimously that the defendant conspired to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by unlawful means, you need not be unanimous as to what those unlawful means were. " It then give those 3 items.

@Jen "Although you must conclude unanimously that the defendant conspired to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by unlawful means, you need not be unanimous as to what those unlawful means were. In determining whether the defendant conspired to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by unlawful means, you may consider the following: (1) violations of the Federal Election Campaign Act otherwise known as FECA; (2) the falsification of other business records; or (3) violation of tax laws. " Also repeats on page 44.

The Jury instructions are the jury instructions because that is how the New York Law is and that law and setup was tested multiple times. I do not see an appealable issue: the law is if any of the three is true, you shall find guilty. BUT the three are not part of the crime and all make the single thing of "Tried to commit another crime"
